# How to store each epoch summary in variable in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create GUI for a Convolutional Neural Network in keras on python. 
I would like to know how to save summary of each model.fit_generator(...) step in a variable each time (so that i could put it in a display box; everytime an epoch completes the displaybox or variable updates with new keras output) when an epoch finishes.

Output reference:
I am talking about the following line to be saved in a variable each time.

```
0s - loss: 0.6551 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.9836 - val_acc: 0.4000
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Callback function that will update your "display box".
Here's an example that prints all the values after each epoch. You can easily change it for your needs.

```
class My_Callback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        return

    def on_train_end(self, logs={}):
        return

    def on_epoch_begin(self, logs={}):
        return

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        for k in self.params['metrics']:
            if k in logs:
                print("Name: %s, Value: %s" % (k, logs[k]))
    def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs={}):
        return

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
        return
```

You should also look at `ProbarLogger()` callback that handles that stdout output you referred to: 
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L245